# How to use resilience4j on calling method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry, resilience4j

I tried to use spring retry for Circuit breaking and retry as below and it is working as expected but issue is unable to configure "maxAttempts/openTimeout/resetTimeout" as env variables (error is should be constants). My question is how use resilience4j to achieve the below requirement?

also please suggest there is a way to pass env variables to "maxAttempts/openTimeout/resetTimeout".

```
@CircuitBreaker(value = {
        MongoServerException.class,
        MongoSocketException.class,
        MongoTimeoutException.class
        MongoSocketOpenException.class},
        maxAttempts =  2,
        openTimeout = 20000L ,
        resetTimeout = 30000L)
public void insertDocument(ConsumerRecord<Long, GenericRecord> consumerRecord){

        retryTemplate.execute(args0 -> {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Inserting record with key -----> %s", consumerRecord.key().toString()));
            BasicDBObject dbObject = BasicDBObject.parse(consumerRecord.value().toString());
            dbObject.put("_id", consumerRecord.key());
            mongoCollection.replaceOne(<<BasicDBObject with id>>, getReplaceOptions());
            return null;
        });

}

@Recover
public void recover(RuntimeException t) {
    LOGGER.info(" Recovering from Circuit Breaker ");
}
```

dependencies used are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
    .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(20000))
    .build();
CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("mongoDB");

RetryConfig retryConfig = RetryConfig.custom().maxAttempts(3)
    .retryExceptions(MongoServerException.class,
        MongoSocketException.class,
        MongoTimeoutException.class
        MongoSocketOpenException.class)
    .ignoreExceptions(CircuitBreakerOpenException.class).build();
Retry retry = Retry.of("helloBackend", retryConfig);

Runnable decoratedRunnable = Decorators.ofRunnable(() -> insertDocument(ConsumerRecord<Long, GenericRecord> consumerRecord))
.withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
.withRetry(retry)
.decorate();

String result = Try.runRunnable(decoratedRunnable )
                .recover(exception -> ...).get();
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, it's event simpler. But please have a look at our user guide.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using resilience4j, but spring-retry.
You should adapt the title of your question.

Comment: Right. As i mentioned i tried to use spring-retry and have issue so wanna use resilience4j to achieve the same functionality.    My requirement is Spring standalone application should connect and insert record in MongoDB and want Circuit Breaker(assume max attempts 3) and Retry (retry attempts 4) on insert method/functionality. So if mongo not available retry 4 times for 3 max attempts and circuit should OPEN for certain time. All configuration is via ENV variables. Any code example will be helpful.